# Is it correct to use the verb 'land' in the passive form?

Tags: passive-voice

I came up with this sentence:

> The plane **was landed** in New York.

My teacher instructed me not to use the verb *land* in the passive form.

I didn't accept that advice, and looked in [freedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Land), but couldn't find enough information to be certain.

Is there anything wrong with using *land* as a verb in the passive form?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: Your can, You just did. You are.

Comment: @choster, yes, I did.

Comment: @Denis Then please edit your post to indicate which dictionary, and why the dictionary was unclear or otherwise insufficient. For additional guidance, I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to use the verb *landed* intransitively, you should phrase the sentence this way:

> The plane landed in New York.

If, instead, you mean to use the verb *landed* transitively, you have two options:

> The plane was landed [by the pilot] in New York.

or

> The pilot landed the plane in New York.

I leave it to you and your teacher to judge which of the two transitive sentences sounds better.

Comment: @Denis - Please don't say thanks in the comments to each answer. Just upvote good answers, and always remember to tick one if it's correct and the best answer given. I know every community say to, but *really* read the guidelines. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Both version are correct:

> The plane was landed in New York.
>
> The plane landed in New York.

The first version emphasizes the fact of the plane being landed by someone (the pilot). The second one just notes the fact of the plane arriving at some place. I would expect the second version to be used much more, but in specific contexts only one of them may work.